# Ubuntu Installer does not see all the logical partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my computer. I have several logical partitions, but the Ubuntu installer shows me only 4 primary partitions. When I run the Ubuntu live CD I have access to all of the logical partitions.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful. Can you provide us with a screenshot of the `GParted` application when running Ubuntu Live, and a screenshot of the partitions page during installation?

Comment: If you are using the Windows "Dynamic Disk" format, then it is proprietary and unsupported.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows "Dynamic Disk" format. 

So, only solution to get Ubuntu is format?

Answer (score 0):

Some third-party Windows partitioning tools can convert a disk from the proprietary "dynamic disk" (aka Logical Disk Manager, or LDM) configuration to a conventional system with primary, extended, and logical partitions. IIRC, both [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) and [Partition Wizard](http://partitionwizard.com/) provide this functionality. Also IIRC, there are free or demo versions of both tools. I'm not very familiar with either of them, though, so I can't help beyond providing the preceding links.

Once the disk is converted to a conventional partitioning setup, the Ubuntu installer should be able to resize the partitions and create partitions for Linux.

Be aware that partitioning operations are inherently dangerous. Thus, I strongly recommend that you make a complete system backup, or at least back up your critical personal data, before using these tools or resizing your Windows partition(s).